# Change values between views - Ionic Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Im using the same controller for 2 views in Ionic, because, its the same information I need.
Let me explain, at the view "config" I use ConfigCtrl, at this view I had a language option, when ng-clicked go to "languages", choose a lang and back to "config" with the same controller ConfigCtrl.
I use radio button component, and if I spec the value on controller, Its ok, the data has change, but at the "config" view its not updating!
Check the code.

```
<span class="item-note">
      {{data.lang| translate}}
</span>
```

/\ Config.html

```
 <ion-radio ng-model="data.lang" ng-click="saveLanguage()" ng-value="'pt_br'">{{'pt_br'| translate}}</ion-radio>
 <ion-radio ng-model="data.lang" ng-click="saveLanguage()" ng-value="'en'">{{'en'| translate}}</ion-radio>
```

/\  Languages.html

```
.controller('configurationCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'UtilsFactory', // TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, UtilsFactory) {
    $scope.data = {};
    //Language scope
    $scope.data.lang = $rootScope.language;

    $scope.saveLanguage = function () {
        $rootScope.language = $scope.data.lang;
        setAnimation('right-animation', '/side-menu/configuration')
    }

}])
```

/\ ConfigCtrl
If I debug the saveLanguage() when clicked its saves, change the value of data.lang, back to the Config.html view, but the value didnt change at the view of 'Config.html", I need to 'refresh' this field on a view, I cant refresh all the page because it will reload the $scope.data.lang

Comment: use $apply to update value

Comment: Can I update only input? Cause I cant reload all the page, the data isnt save yet